# vue.js - issues with the background image covering on viewport size on Desktop

Tags: vue.js

I have a component game that interact with a data.json file where all my data is (including different background images). And in the page game i want different backgrounds so i did this:

```
v-bind:style="{ 'background': 'url('+ step.img +')' + 'no-repeat center fixed'}"
```

But when i add "cover" to the list the image disappear from the viewport.

The path is `/game/:id`, so this is how you go to one page to another within the same component.

PS: it's a game where there's a question with multiple solutions and you have to choose one to pass the step and go to the one following...

```
v-bind:style="{ 'background': 'url('+ step.img +')' + 'no-repeat center fixed cover'}"
```

doesn't work

this is in my `data.json` file:

```
"img": "../assets/images/bg1.png"
```

@DrCord this is what i wrote

```html
<template>
  <div rel="preload" v-bind:style="{ 'background': 'url('+ step.img +')' + 'no-repeat center fixed' }">
  <section>
       <h1>{{ step.title }}</h1>
    </section>
   
    <ul>
      <li v-on:click="doActions(action)" 
        v-for="action in step.actions" 
        :key="action.step"
        v-show="canDoAction(action)"
      >

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

@Daniel Do you mean just an img tag ( Sorry i'm a beginner )

Comment: We would need to see your html markup.

Comment: Have you tried testing it with plain html? Doesn't look like it's at all related to Vue.js if your element works with the **ONLY** difference being the `cover` part of the style attribute

Comment: I bet your problem is that your ``data.json`` points to image files relative to ``data.json`` location. Use an absolute path from website root.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background) cover in the compact background attributes mode should be used with `/` before it, like so: `'url('+ step.img +')' + 'no-repeat center / cover'`, check my working snippet answer below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <div rel="preload" :style="{ 'background': 'url('+ step.img +')' + 'no-repeat center / cover' }">
  <section>
       <h1>{{ step.title }}</h1>
    </section>
   
    <ul>
      <li @click="doActions(action)" 
        v-for="action in step.actions" 
        :key="action.step"
        v-show="canDoAction(action)"
      >

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#el',
    data: {
      step: {
        title: 'This is title',
        img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1000'
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```